# Why MDN recommends += instead of the concat() method?

Tags: javascript, performance, string-concatenation

According to this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat#performance), it seems `+=` is preferred over `concat()` for performance issues. So I use the following sample code to test.

```
var str = "";
var startTime = performance.now()
for(var i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
   str = str.concat(i);
}
var endTime = performance.now()
console.log(`concat took ${endTime - startTime} ms`)

str = "";
startTime = performance.now()
for(var i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
   str += i;
}
endTime = performance.now()
console.log(`+= took ${endTime - startTime} ms`)
```

But I don't see a significant difference until I increase the loop to 10,000,000 times. Here are some outputs I obtains when running on Chrome.

```
concat took 3067.600000023842 ms
+= took 2799 ms
```

```
concat took 2751.5 ms
+= took 2280.199999988079 ms
```

```
concat took 2865.699999988079 ms
+= took 1857.5999999642372 ms
```

```
concat took 2909.7000000476837 ms
+= took 2183.599999964237 ms
```

If you compare `+=` and `StringBuilder.append()` with Java, you will observe a huge difference (e.g., 3 ms vs. 3000 ms) even testing on a loop of 10000 times.

So in which case can I observe a significant difference between `+=` and `concat()` on JavaScript?

Comment: complete speculation: += reallocs, concat mallocs

Comment: I see some uncontrolled variables here. Have you tried the same experiment with a large string ? and a string that's not always the same length on each iteration ? Have you tried calling concat() with 10000000 arguments instead of calling it 10000000 times with one argument ?